# No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Double'

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I have defined a model, with the parameter Type as "Double".

```
@Size(max = 50)
private Double priority;
```

When I try to save , Hiberante throws following exception[1].

What is the validation I miss here? (I tried adding @Size, and removed that , But same issue occurs)

I post to my endpoint, like ;

```
{
...
"priority":100.0,
..
}
```

[1]

```
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Double'. Check configuration for 'priority'
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
    at com.cdi.crud.infra.Crud.save(Crud.java:488)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Size` constraint is used to specify the minimum and maximum length of string values. You should be using the `@DecimalMax` constraint instead:

```
@DecimalMax("50.0")
private Double priority;
```

Note, however, that the spec indicates that double and float values are not supported due to possible rounding errors, and that the provider (Hibernate, in your case) might provide approximative support. In any case, it would be better to switch to a `BigDecimal`:

```
@DecimalMax("50.0")
private BigDecimal priority;
```